# Matplotlib 2.0.2 ignoring figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I recently upgraded to the new matplotlib 2.0.2. The new default colours are great, but now my requested dimensions of my plots are ignored. i.e. I'm expecting a plot that is 8.2 × 10 cm, with a dpi of 600. My plot comes out at the correct width, but the height is incorrect.

Can anyone help point out where I'm going wrong here? Example code below:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from numpy import *

# made up data
z = linspace(0.0,1.0, 100)
a = linspace(0.0,2.0, 100)
b = linspace(0.5,2.1, 100)

# fig size and positioning
figx = 8.2 # width of image in cm
figy = 10.0 # height of image  in cm
x0 = 0.15 # left edge of plot (between 0-1)
y0 = 0.15 # bottom edge of plot (between 0-1)
xw = 0.7 # width of plot (between 0-1)
yh = 0.7 # height of plot (between 0-1)

# Draw plot
figure(figsize=(figx/2.54,figy/2.54))
axes([x0,y0,xw,yh])
plot(a,z, label = 'label1')
plot(b,z, label = 'label2')
xlabel('x label goes here', labelpad=1)
ylabel('y label goes here', labelpad=1)
legend(frameon=False)   
savefig('test.png', dpi=600)
close('all')
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. When I run the code with matplotlib 2.0.2, the produced png has a size of 8.2 x 10.0 cm, just as desired.

Comment: Well this is both a relief and a source of confusion... I get different behaviour as I change the dpi of the saved figure. But I can't seem to work out why. Any explanations/ potential solutions would be very much welcome.

i.e. 
dpi = 200, I get a figure that is 8.18 × 9.98 cm (644 × 786 px). 
dpi = 400, I get a figure that is 8.18 × 6.36 cm (1288 × 1001 px)
dpi = 600, I get a figure that is 8.18 × 4.23 cm (1932 × 1000 px)

Thanks,
-Dylan

Comment: What you're telling is that the figure **shape** changes depending on the dpi. Some are higher than wide, some are wider than high. That is impossible. How do you "measure" the pixels?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the code _should_ work. I'm going to uninstall  and get a newer Python(x,y) release. For the record, I determine the pixels by (in Windows) right clicking on my output file --> properties --> details. Thanks.